# Unable use IBM mobile first console: the runtime does not exist

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-studio

Whenever I am trying to deploy application its showing following message? How can I resolve it?

> FWLSE3030E: The runtime "HelloWorld" does not exist in the Worklight
>   administration database. The database may be corrupted.

I am using Eclipse Luna Java EE 64 bits , IBM MoblieFirst Studio 6.3, JRE 1.8 and JDK 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IBM MobileFirst Platform does not support Java 8.

Downgrade to either Java 6 or Java 7.
It should then work.

Comment: I've selected the Java Environment 1.6 from eclipse preferences (I've actually both 1.6 and 1.8 JRE), restarted eclipse and then it worked.